# How can I make a subclass of UITabBarController inherit from UIViewController too?

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a third party **SDK** which provides a custom `UIViewController`. I am not sure of the exact functionality since it's closed source.

I want to create a subclass of `UITabBarController` that also inherits the functionality from the third party UIViewController. Is that possible using **Swift**?

Answer (score 0):

No, Swift only supports single inheritance of superclasses, and multiple inheritance of protocols.  You could use delegation though - delegate to one of the classes in question.  Without knowing your intents, it hard to be more specific.  From the face of it though, it feels like a bad idea from the outset, I would look for cleaner high level solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not clean, but the methods I need are only on this subclass of UIViewController, so I don't have much of a choice

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to subclass `UITabBarController`. Instead create a `UITabBarController` and set an instance of the custom view controller class as one of it's view controllers:

```
tabBarController.setViewControllers([viewController], NO)
```